# MongoDB KeyError with $exists condition

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and i'm trying to access a collection using two conditions, when "orgId" exists, then look for the value. However, I get a "KeyError". I thought that the first condition in my query would solve it, but still appears.

```
for organizations in collection1.find({ "orgId": { "$exists": "true" } }, {"_id" : row[0]}):
         print (organizations['orgId'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MongoDBconnect.py", line 15, in <module>
    print (organizations['orgId'])
KeyError: 'orgId'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: If I don't quote it I get: SyntaxError: invalid syntax...

Comment: @PrajvalM this is a python dictionary not a json structure.

Comment: Use `organizations.get(key)` instead of `organizations[key]`.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum It solves the error, thanks. But now I can see that it doesn't store into organizations any other key rather then "_id"... The print just shows "None", but I'm sure that the Key is called "orgId" and that collection1 has it.

Comment: What is `collection1`?

Comment: A MongoDB document with several fields as "_id" or "orgId"

Comment: Okay, see my answer for info

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are telling `find` to only return results with the field `"_id"` in them.

If you omit the second argument of `.find(query, projection)`, you get the result as-is. Otherwise, you have to define what fields it should contain.

Read this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just let me know if there is anything else you need.